# Drupal Views adding a view to node-customcontenttype.tpl.php

Tags: views, theming

I've created a "homepage" content type, and I've created the node-homepage.tpl.php template file, but it doesn't seem it is used, even after I cleared the cache about 10 times.

I am also trying to display a view in this custom template file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you should use two dashes : `node--content-type.tpl.php`.

Embeding view:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('articles','block', $node->nid); ?>
```

`articles` - name of view, `block` - type of view, `$node->nid` - argument.